# How to bind a LocalDate to a TextField bidirectionally in JavaFX

Tags: date, binding, javafx-8

I am trying to bind an `ObjectProperty<LocalDate>` on a DTO to a `TextField` and am having trouble getting this to work.

This is how I have it set up:

```
dateOfBirthTextField.setTextFormatter(new TextFormatter<>(new LocalDateEnhancedStringConverter()));

person.birthdayProperty().bindBidirectional(dateOfBirthTextField.textProperty(), new LocalDateEnhancedStringConverter());
```

But this is giving me the following compile error:

> The method bindBidirectional(Property) in the type ObjectProperty is not applicable for the arguments (StringProperty, LocalDateEnhancedStringConverter)

Not quite sure what to try next?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the JavaDoc:

> `public <T> void bindBidirectional(Property<T> other, StringConverter<T> converter)`
>
> Create a bidirectional binding between this `StringProperty` and another arbitrary property. 
>   Parameters:
>
> `other` - the other Property
>
> `converter` - the StringConverter used to convert between this **StringProperty** and the other Property

(bold is mine)

So you should do the binding in the opposite order, to bind  the `StringProperty` that comes from the textfield to the "other" property, the birthday property:

```
dateOfBirthTextField.textProperty()
    .bindBidirectional(
        person.birthdayProperty(), 
        new LocalDateEnhancedStringConverter());
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use a [DatePicker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/date-picker.htm#CCHHJBEA) instead. You can then bind the [value property](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ComboBoxBase.html#valueProperty).

Comment: Unfortunately my users do not want a date picker so I'm stuck with this use case.